# Smarty multidimensional Array

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have a multidimensional array like this :

```
    $products   Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (2)
  0 => Array (73)
    id_product => "1"
    id_supplier => "1"
    id_manufacturer => "1"
    id_tax_rules_group => "1"
    id_category_default => "2"
    id_color_default => "2"
    on_sale => "0"
    online_only => "0"
    ean13 => "0"
    upc => null
    ecotax => "0.000000"
    quantity => "50"
    minimal_quantity => "1"
    price => 189.05
    wholesale_price => "70.000000"
    unity => null
    unit_price_ratio => "0.000000"
    additional_shipping_cost => "0.00"
    reference => ""
    supplier_reference => ""
    location => null
    width => "0"
    height => "0"
    depth => "0"
    weight => "0.5"
    out_of_stock => "2"
    quantity_discount => "0"
    customizable => "0"
    uploadable_files => "0"
    text_fields => "0"
    active => "1"
    available_for_order => "1"
    condition => "new"
    show_price => "1"
    indexed => "1"
    cache_is_pack => "0"
    cache_has_attachments => "0"
    cache_default_attribute => "31"
    date_add => "2011-12-02 17:35:57"
    date_upd => "2011-12-02 17:35:57"
    id_product_attribute => "31"
    description => "<p><strong><span style="font-size: sm..."
    description_short => "<p>New design. New features. Now in 8..."
    available_now => "In stock"
    available_later => ""
    link_rewrite => "ipod-nano"
    meta_description => ""
    meta_keywords => ""
    meta_title => ""
    name => "iPod Nano"
    id_image => "1-37"
    legend => "iPod Nano"
    manufacturer_name => "Apple Computer, Inc"
    tax_name => "TVA FR 19.6%"
    rate => "19.600"
    category_default => "iPods"
    new => "1"
    orderprice => "149.0000002400000"
    attribute => Array (16)
      25 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Blue"
          id_product_attribute => "25"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "25"
      26 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Blue"
          id_product_attribute => "26"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "26"
      27 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "27"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Yellow"
          id_product_attribute => "27"
      28 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "28"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Yellow"
          id_product_attribute => "28"
      29 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Metal"
          id_product_attribute => "29"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "29"
      30 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Metal"
          id_product_attribute => "30"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "30"
      32 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Black"
          id_product_attribute => "32"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "32"
      33 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Orange"
          id_product_attribute => "33"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "33"
      34 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Orange"
          id_product_attribute => "34"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "34"
      35 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Pink"
          id_product_attribute => "35"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "35"
      36 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Pink"
          id_product_attribute => "36"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "36"
      39 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Green"
          id_product_attribute => "39"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "39"
      40 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Green"
          id_product_attribute => "40"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "40"
      41 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "41"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Purple"
          id_product_attribute => "41"
      42 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "8Go"
          id_product_attribute => "42"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Purple"
          id_product_attribute => "42"
      31 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Black"
          id_product_attribute => "31"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "31"
```

In my tpl i have this :

```
 {foreach from=$product.attribute key='id_attribute' item='attribute'} 
<li>{$attribute}</li>
{/foreach}
```

This code return me an array.

How can i display all the value like this :

- Color blue , disk space : 16Go  (array 25)
- Color blue, disk space : 8Go (array 26)
- ...

I have to make multiple foreach ?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need an inner `{foreach}` block.

```
{foreach from=$product.attribute key='id_attribute' item='attribute'} 

    <li>

        {foreach from=$attribute key='id_property' item='property'} 
            {$property.public_group_name}
            {$property.attribute_name}
        {/foreach}

    </li>

{/foreach}
```