# SMARTY : verify if a value is in a multimensionnal array

Tags: arrays, smarty

I have this multidimensionnal array in smarty :

```
attribute => Array (16)
  25 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Blue"
      id_product_attribute => "25"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "25"
  26 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Blue"
      id_product_attribute => "26"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "26"
  27 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "27"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Yellow"
      id_product_attribute => "27"
  28 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "28"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Yellow"
      id_product_attribute => "28"
  29 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Metal"
      id_product_attribute => "29"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "29"
  30 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Metal"
      id_product_attribute => "30"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "30"
  32 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Black"
      id_product_attribute => "32"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "32"
  33 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Orange"
      id_product_attribute => "33"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "33"
  34 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Orange"
      id_product_attribute => "34"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "34"
  35 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Pink"
      id_product_attribute => "35"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "35"
  36 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Pink"
      id_product_attribute => "36"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "36"
  39 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Green"
      id_product_attribute => "39"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "39"
  40 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Green"
      id_product_attribute => "40"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "40"
  41 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "41"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Purple"
      id_product_attribute => "41"
  42 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "8Go"
      id_product_attribute => "42"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Purple"
      id_product_attribute => "42"
  31 => Array (2)
    0 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Color"
      attribute_name => "Black"
      id_product_attribute => "31"
    1 => Array (3)
      public_group_name => "Disk space"
      attribute_name => "16Go"
      id_product_attribute => "31"
```

I can display all array thanks to this solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401154/smarty-multidimensional-array/8401230#8401230) :

```
{foreach from=$product.attribute key='id_attribute' item='attribute'} 

<li>

    {foreach from=$attribute key='id_property' item='property'} 
        {$property.public_group_name}
        {$property.attribute_name}
    {/foreach}

</li>
```

{/foreach}

The result is like this :

- Color Blue Disk space 16Go
- Color Blue Disk space 8Go
- Disk space 16Go Color Yellow
- Disk space 8Go Color Yellow
- Color Metal Disk space 16Go
- Color Metal Disk space 8Go
- Color Black Disk space 8Go
- Color Orange Disk space 16Go
- Color Orange Disk space 8Go
- Color Pink Disk space 16Go
- Color Pink Disk space 8Go
- Color Green Disk space 16Go
- Color Green Disk space 8Go
- Disk space 16Go Color Purple
- Disk space 8Go Color Purple
- Color Black Disk space 16Go

NOw, i want to display result only if a line contain "Blue".
This array will not been display because he has attribute name = Orange:

```
33 => Array (2)
        0 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Color"
          attribute_name => "Orange"
          id_product_attribute => "33"
        1 => Array (3)
          public_group_name => "Disk space"
          attribute_name => "16Go"
          id_product_attribute => "33"
```

How can i do that ? 
With in_array, can i verify if a value is in a multidimensionnal array ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may do the job:

```
{foreach from=$product.attribute key='id_attribute' item='attribute'} 
{* 
  Test if the first or second element of this array has 
    public_group_name  "Color" 
    attribute_name "Blue"
*}
{if ($attribute[0].public_group_name == "Color" && $attribute[0].attribute_name == "Blue") || ($attribute[1].public_group_name == "Color" && $attribute[1].attribute_name == "Blue")}
<li>

    {foreach from=$attribute key='id_property' item='property'} 
        {$property.public_group_name}
        {$property.attribute_name}
    {/foreach}

</li>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: the pb is that color attribute is not always in the first : array [0].  maybe with :
{if $attribute[0].public_group_name == "Blue" or $attribute[1] etc...}